# Magical color squares

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

Can you discover the meaning of this image?

[image: puzzle]

Comment: Is "Steganography" a fitting tag?

Comment: @Daedric i am not sure... :(

Comment: "the practice of concealing messages or information within other non-secret text or data." - google===="A puzzle that consists in detecting a message that is not overtly visible from the outside." - Puzzling SE. Also generally used for encrypted images due to the former / latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you wanted to be found or there is more to it.

> get the rgb colors and translate those into their ascii correspondents: 
> [105 - 110 - 32] - [97 - 114 - 99] - [117 - 109 - 32] - [118 - 101 - 114] - [105 - 116 - 97] - [115 -  32 - 101] - [115 - 116 - 33]
>  which translates into : **In arcum veritas est!** which further translates in **The truth is in the bow/rainbow!** (I mean, I think it translates to this)

Comment: i tried the RGB too...but i tried to find the name of the colours using them...I guess I chose the wrong path.. :p

Comment: @manshu, I also thought of that, but I noticed a way too small color difference and stop going on that path :D (also, like all men, I only know a few colors)

Comment: maybe there is a better translation? (spoiler: rainbow)

Comment: @Bort, I hadn't had any latin classes but I definitely like the rainbow one. It fits will the color thingy.